# Load per deflection of springs

Tags: mechanical-engineering, springs

I am working on a project using springs. What is the maximum load per deflection of springs available in market?

Comment: Your question lacks context. Why do you want maximum load per deflection, which corresponds to stiffness? Stiffness is very high for solid bodies, which is the limit of a spring with almost infinite stiffness.

Comment: Anything you want. There are many companies that make custom designed springs. Spring stiffness values like 10 tons/inch are standard parts - you could go much higher than that if you need it.

Comment: @alephzero  What could be the range of cost for such a spring with 10 tons per inch

Comment: @Pranav Google is your friend. And this question is unanswerable, unless you tell us whether you want a 10-tons-per-inch spring that is 1 inch long or 10 feet long!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no sensible answer to this. Springs are designed to have a relatively high deflection relative to their  to ultimate strength. Once you want very stiff springs you can just use solid bars of steel.

The trick with spring design is to end up with a product which has a *specific* set of properties and it is possible to make arbitrarily stiff or light springs. What may be more difficult is combining a desired stiffness and capacity with a particular set of dimensions and lifetime.

Equally any answer may also depend on what you define as the difference between a spring and a structure as all solid materials are essentially springs for a given load range.

Comment: The building I'm working in right now has a bunch of huge hollowish steel beams going underneath the street to support the large open hall below.  The steel beams act like springs, and they aren't tuned yet.  I work above the street and any time a truck drives by the whole office oscillates a noticeable amount; feels like inches but I'm not actually sure.  My point being, buildings definitely can behave like springs considering I can feel the harmonic motion.